# How to deal with "un-appreciated" answer?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

```
User A ask question.
User B came across the question, he knew the answer to question.
User B answer the question provided by User A.
User A view the answer.
```

But.. User A doesn't:

- Give any feedback to the answer; e.g. comment on answer.
- Upvote/Downvote the answer.
- (Possibly) abandon the answer.

How to deal with this type of user ?

Comment: Throwing more energy at a black hole user isn't going to fix their behaviour. Just move on and find somebody who does appreciate your help. They do exist. If the only reason you're providing support on here is for the fake internet points attached to votes, you probably need to readjust.